# Managing queue in second thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I created thread which is responsible for doing some long operation on passed data. All data are put to the queue in main thread, then second thread gets this data, manipulate them and returns to map which contains ID of executed data and result. Class looks like that:

```
#include <memory>
#include <future>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

typedef unsigned int Key;

class DatabaseWorker
{
public:
    DatabaseWorker()
    {
        startThread();
    }

    ~DatabaseWorker()
    {
        stopThread();
    }

    void startThread()
    {
        std::cout << "starting thread" << std::endl;
        m_futureObj = m_exitSignal.get_future();
        m_thread = std::thread(&DatabaseWorker::work, this);
    }

    void stopThread()
    {
        std::cout << "stopping thread" << std::endl;
        m_exitSignal.set_value();
        if (m_thread.joinable())
            m_thread.join();
    }

    void work()
    {
        std::cout << "thread started" << std::endl;
        bool bEmpty;
        std::pair<Key, std::string> data;
        while (m_futureObj.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) == std::future_status::timeout)
        {
            //Check queue size
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                bEmpty = m_requests.empty();
            }
            if (!bEmpty)
            {
                std::cout << "something in queue" << std::endl;
                //Get data from queue
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                    data = m_requests.front();
                    m_requests.pop();
                }

                Key id = data.first;
                std::string str = data.second;
                //HERE do some operation with string
                str += "_123";

                //Prepare result
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                    m_results.insert(std::make_pair(id, str));

                    //Inform conditional about data
                    m_conditionals.find(id)->second.second = true;
                    m_conditionals.find(id)->second.first->notify_one();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Key addToQueue(const std::string &data)
    {
        std::cout << "adding to queue" << std::endl;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);  //lock
        m_requests.push(std::make_pair(m_nID, data));   //adddata to queue
        m_conditionals.insert(std::make_pair(m_nID, std::make_pair(std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>(), bool(false))));
        return m_nID++;
    }

    std::string getResult(Key id)
    {
        std::cout << "getting result" << std::endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        //Check if data ready
        m_conditionals.find(id)->second.first->wait(lock, [&](){
            return m_conditionals.find(id)->second.second;  //return bool data
        });

        //If data ready
        auto result = m_results.find(id)->second;   //Get data from thread
        //Delete data
        m_results.erase(m_results.find(id));    //HERE HEAP ISSUE OCCURS SOMETIMES!!!
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::queue<std::pair<Key, std::string>> m_requests;
    std::map<Key, std::string> m_results;
    std::map < Key, std::pair< std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable>, bool>> m_conditionals;

    std::promise<void> m_exitSignal;
    std::future<void> m_futureObj;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::thread m_thread;

    Key m_nID = 0;
};
```

Then in main function I'm adding some data and waiting for response from thread:

```
int main()
{
    DatabaseWorker dbWorker;
    std::ostringstream stringStream;
    std::string data;
    std::vector<Key> keys;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        stringStream.str("");
        stringStream << "data_" << i;
        data = stringStream.str();
        keys.push_back(dbWorker.addToQueue(data));
    }

    for each (Key key in keys)
    {
        std::cout << "key: " << key << " data: " << dbWorker.getResult(key) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is that sometimes during calling `getResult()` method I get memory error in place `m_results.erase(m_results.find(id))`:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression _pFirstBlock == pHead
```

Where is the lack of my understanding/implementation?

Comment: Don't forget `for (int i = 0; ...)` is allowed and is encouraged.

Comment: `for each (Key key in keys)` does not look like C++.

Comment: I'm using VisualStudio 2013 and C++11

Comment: @drewpol That's not C++11. It looks more like Microsoft's proprietary abomination, C++/CLI.

Comment: `for each` is a C++/CLI extension. You should use standard range loop instead: `for (Key key : keys)`

Comment: Even though you presently have only one working thread, you should write your code to not depend on that as the above code can fails with 2 or more working threads as you don't the data at the same time you check if you have data. Thus multiple threads could thing that data is available but their is data only for part of them.

Comment: Given that you retrieve data in order and wait for each item to be ready, I think that your code is more complex that it needs to be.